# What is the replacement for file_column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is `has_attached_file` the same as the old `file_column`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. `has_attached_file` is a macro introduced by the [Paperclip](https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip) gem.

I don't remember about any `file_column` method in Rails. Perhaps it was the [`file_column`](https://github.com/tekin/file_column) plugin.

Comment: It is the plugin. I have added it to vendor/plugins but is getting this error in view: uninitialized constant FileColumn::ClassMethods::Inflector